# Read access control with Mercurial and Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, security, mercurial

I've set up Mercurial via Apache (`hgwebdir.cgi`). 
I would like to have the same functionality as when using Subversion and AuthzSVNAccessFile, in which I can restrict which user has read or write permissions for every single repository. The [acl extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/AclExtension) only controls how changes are brought to the repository, as does the `allow_push` directive. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an `allow_read` directive that can be added to a repository hgrc that works the same way as `allow_push`.  If specified, and the user accessing the hgwebdir CGI script is not in the list, the project doesn't even show up at the index page.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The allow_read directive does not appear in the hgbook, nor in the wiki at selenic.com when it describes hgrc.

Answer (score 1):

They're served up via apache or lighttpd, right? So you could maybe hide them behind normal webby ACL things? (basic auth, etc)

Note that, as with git, as a consequence of they way they work, you're never going to be able to have control at any finer granularity than the repository level.  You can grant whole-repo access or not, but never just 'you can read this one file in the repo' access.