# Controlling clone access to multiple mercurial repos served via hgwebdir.cgi

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, mercurial, version-control

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Read access control with Mercurial and Apache](https://serverfault.com/questions/33774/read-access-control-with-mercurial-and-apache)

I'm trying to host multiple Mercurial repositories for my clients. I need to control access to each repository individually — not just push access, but clone as well.

I've got an `.htaccess` set which requires authentication globally:

```
AuthUserFile /path/to/hgweb.passwd
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
AuthName "Chris Lawlor Client Mercurial Repositories"
AuthType Basic
<Limit GET POST PUT>
    Require valid-user
</Limit>
<FilesMatch "\.(htaccess|passwd|config|bak)$">
    Order Allow,Deny
    Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Then in each repository, I've got a `.hg/hgrc` file requiring a valid user

```
[web]
allow_push = <comma seperated user list>
```

This almost does what I need. The problem is that I need to add *all* my clients to `hgweb.passwd`, which gives them clone access to *all* of the repositories.

The only solution I can think of is to have another `.htaccess` and `.passwd` file in *each* repository. I don't really want to do that though, seems a little convoluted. I can already specify a list of authorized users for each repository in that repos' `hgrc` file with the `allow_push` setting. If only there were an `allow_clone` setting as well...

All the documentation I've found for `hgwebdir.cgi` is incomplete. I've read:

- http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/HgWebDirStepByStep
- http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/collaborating-with-other-people.html#sec:collab:cgi
- http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/collaborating-with-other-people.html

And others. I've yet to find a comprehensive list of `hgrc` settings.

I guess this is as much an Apache question than a Mercurial question.

Unless I can find a better approach, I'll be going with a seperate `.htaccess` and `.passwd` file for each repo.

This is a virtual host on Webfaction if it matters — set up roughly like [described in their documentation](http://docs.webfaction.com/software/mercurial.html).

**Edit:** Looks like any `.htaccess` files in the client repos will be ignored. I think this is because all requests are being served by `hgwebdir.cgi` in the webroot, so only the `.htaccess` in the webroot takes affect.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer in the [hgrc(5) man page](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#web):

> **allow_read**
>
> If the user has not already been denied repository access due to the contents of `deny_read`, this list determines whether to grant repository access to the user. If this list is not empty, and the user is unauthenticated or not present in the list (separated by whitespace or `,`), then access is denied for the user. If the list is empty or not set, then access is permitted to all users by default. Setting `allow_read` to the special value `*` is equivalent to it not being set (i.e. access is permitted to all users). The contents of the `allow_read` list are examined after the `deny_read` list.